# I cannot make table In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE items 
ADD CONSTRAINT member_1  
FOREIGN KEY(Member_ID)
REFERENCES users(UserID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**MySQL said:**

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop`.`#sql-1650_234`, CONSTRAINT `member_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`Member_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

You must to fix incorrect values before create new constraint:

```
Update items SET member_ID = null
where member_ID not in (select userID from users)
```